# node.js body-parser field writing

Tags: node.js

I want to write all 3 HTML form fields (name, email, message) to a text file. When I try to call req.body.message OR req.body.email it doesn't work, I can only seem to get name to work. What am I missing?

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

//app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
  res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".');
  fs.writeFile('file.txt', req.body.name, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('Wrote data to file.txt');
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  });
 });

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
});
```

HTML Form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>CSS3 Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contact">
    <h1>Send an email</h1>
    <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/myaction" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" />

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" />

            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea id="message" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" value="Send message" />

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the "name" attribute to your HTML

```
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" />

        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
```